# Scope name is not being isolated in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and was messing a bit with `$routeProvider`, I have the following in my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>AngularJS Practice</h1>
  <div ng-view>

  </div>
</div>
```

Inside my app.js file I wrote the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/second', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })
}]);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.name = "Main controller";
}]);

myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'Second controller';
}])
```

And in each template, I simply wrote:

`second.html`:

```
<h1>Second</h1>

<h3>Scope name {{ name }}</h3>
```

`main.html`:

```
<h1>Main</h1>

<h3>Scope name: {{ name }}</h3>
```

I expected the $scope object to be different in each controller but somehow when I got to the second route (`'/second'`) the scope name is still "Main controller". Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `controller: 'mainController'` in both states.

Change the following:

```
.when('/second', {
  templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
  controller: 'secondController'
})
```

Comment: Jesus christ. Thank you

Comment: No prob. Please vote up and accept the simple answer. Thanks.